# NSTimer With ActivityIndicator

Tags: ios, nstimer, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to stop `ActivityIndicator` after some time. I guess this can be achieved if I call a method after some time which stops activity indicator.

It can be achieved using `NSTimer`, but I don't know how. An example with code snippet will be great.

Comment: What do you mean by timer condition? Please specify in some more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's i want to use NSTimer with activityindicator.. like after a particular time my activityIndicator get hide.. and another  tool like UIButton get displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `.h` class,

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activity;
```

And used this code to your implementation class,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //initialise activityIndicator and add it to view
    activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activity.frame = CGRectMake(150,200, 20, 20);
    [self.view addSubview:activity];
    [activity startAnimating];

    //call timer to fire after your required time
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:self selector:@selector(timerMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Timer Action,

```
-(void) timerMethod : (NSTimer *) theTimer {
    // after 1.5 seconds, the activity indicator will be hidden.
      [activity stopAnimating];
}
```